# KNeighborsClassifier query data dimension must match training data dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to find the training error on a model across different values for k.

Here is my code:

```
x_eq = np.array(equal_scales[['x1','x2']])
y_eq = np.array(equal_scales[['category']])
y_eq = y_eq.ravel()

train_error_list = []
for i in range(30):
    i = i+1
    knn4 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    knn4.fit(x_eq, y_eq)
    #evaluate accuracy training-error
    train_accuracy = knn2.score(x_eq, y_eq)
    train_error = 1 - train_accuracy
    train_error_list.append(train_error)
```

`x_eq` is a numpy array with shape (100,2) looking like this:

```
array([[ -1.33255739e-01,  -1.68917051e+00],
       [  1.22342923e+00,  -4.58386227e-01],
       [ -7.50266300e-01,   1.84619283e-01],
       [ -5.75475318e-01,   7.98265338e-01],
       [ -2.59622198e-01,  -8.56879897e-01],
       [ -4.54110670e-01,   1.36136079e+00],
       [  6.87128005e-01,  -1.56213731e+00],
       [ -8.52919125e-01,  -2.15160667e-01],
       [  1.08863420e+00,   1.88649799e+00],
       [ -6.08777374e-05,   1.43126563e+00],
       [ -4.00791901e-01,   2.06030370e-01],
   [  7.36267212e-01,   2.29608975e-01],
```

y_eq is a numpy array with shape (100,) looking like this:

```
array(['B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B',
       'C', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C',
       'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', '
```

I get the following error message:

`ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension`

I have fit a very similar model earlier and I am not sure how this one is different from my previous tests. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please give the full error trace.  What line is giving the `ValueError`?

Comment: HI Thanks for the reply... the value error was coming from 

`knn4.fit(x_eq, y_eq)`.

but I've actually found my mistake. I was scoring the data on a model that I had trained earlier `knn2` vs `knn4` which I was training here - i copied the code and did not adjust this! THanks again